# Newbie Java, Else has no If

Tags: java

Working on a java project and having difficulty, the second else if statement brings up multiple errors claiming that } is not the proper start of a method and that the else has no if statement. Been stuck on this for hours. :-/

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Practice_4_4
{
  public static void main(String[]args)
  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int x;
    int y;
    int coordinate;

    System.out.print("Enter the X coordinate: ");
    x = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the Y coordinate: ");
    y = scan.nextInt();


    if (x == 0 && y == 0)
        System.out.print("(0,0) is the origin");

    else if (x > 0 || x < 0 && y == 0)
        System.out.print("(" + x + ",0) is on the X axis");

    else if (y > 0 || y < 0 && x == 0)

  }

 }
```

Comment: `else if (y>0 || y<0 && x==0)` ... what? What is supposed to happen if this is true? Please also note that good code formatting helps you with your debugging and sloppy formatting, especially sloppy indentation, does just the opposite. A little effort towards clean and regular indentation will go a long way towards helping you to debug your code better.

Comment: With apologies; reading unindented code is like trying to make sense out of a @HovercraftFullOfEels! ;-)

Comment: Among other things, one should make it a habit to always use (properly indented) `{}` to enclose the `if` and `else` clauses, even if the clause is only a single statement.  Doing this prevents a multitude of errors.

Answer (score 1):

Note that an if condition must be followed by a code statement or block, and this statement or block will only be called if the if condition is true. Your last `else if...` has no statement or code block after it.

So this statement: `else if (y>0 || y<0 && x==0)` should be followed by some code block that is called if the statement is true. For example:

```
else if (y>0 || y<0 && x==0) {
  // this block is called if the condition is true.
}
```

As an aside, please also note that good code formatting helps you with your debugging and sloppy formatting, especially sloppy indentation, does just the opposite. A little effort towards clean and regular indentation will go a long way towards helping you to debug your code better.

So improved formatting would look something like...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Practice_4_4 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      int x;
      int y;
      int coordinate; // what are you going to do with this variable?

      System.out.print("Enter the X coordinate: ");
      x = scan.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Enter the Y coordinate: ");
      y = scan.nextInt();

      if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
         System.out.print("(0,0) is the origin");
      } else if (x > 0 || x < 0 && y == 0) {
         System.out.print("(" + x + ",0) is on the X axis");
      } else if (y > 0 || y < 0 && x == 0) {
         // you need this block here
      }
   }
}
```

As another aside, at this stage of your programming education, you should strongly consider enclosing *all* if statements, else statements, for loops, while loops, any kind of loops, all with curly braces so that they're enclosed within a code block. Doing this will prevent future errors, where you add a line of code thinking that it is controlled by an if boolean condition when in fact it is not.

Answer (score 0):

```
class IfElse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x1=0, y1=0, x2=1, y2=1, x3=1, y3=0, x4=0, y4=1;

        // 0, 0 is origin
        // 1, 1 is quadrant
        // 1, 0 is X axis
        // 0, 1 is Y axis

        ifElse(x1, y1);
        ifElse(x2, y2);
        ifElse(x3, y3);
        ifElse(x4, y4);

    }

    public static void ifElse(int x, int y) {

        if(x == 0 && y == 0)
            System.out.println("point is on origin...");
        else {
            if(x == 0)
                System.out.println("point is on Y axis...");
            else if(y == 0)
                System.out.println("point is on X axis...");
            else
                System.out.println("point is in a quadrant...");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: if you use an empty conditional you need to have curly brackets, because the compiler is looking for the next semicolon-terminated statement to exit the conditional block... if(this){ } is legal while what you wrote is not..

Comment: also... it would help everybody (especially yourself) if you use a clean style in your code (uniform indents)

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem, because you are newbie in Java programming language. Buddy, just listen me up, in the last else if block you haven’t anything and last else if block is useless. You can fix it like:

```
else if (y > 0 || y < 0 && x == 0){
System.out.println(“Something!”);
}
```

I hope, it was useful for you! Good luck, my java friend ; - )